# Execute javascript or C# code on webcontrol

Tags: c#, input, webbrowser-control

I'm making an Windows Form Application in C# with Visual Studio 2010.

What I want to do, is to go to an page with the webbrowser control, and then insert an value in an input box, and submit the form.

The navigating part isn't that hard, and is already handled. But i can't get the text inserting working...

The problem is that the input doesn't have in ID, only the name.

In JQuery the code will looks like this:

```
$('input[name="searchstring"]').val("hoi");
```

But how would that look in C# code? (or combi of C# and Javascript / Jquery)

I already have this code:

```
HtmlElementCollection playerSearchBox = webBrowserSearchPlayer.Document.GetElementsByTagName("searchstring");
playerSearchBox[0].InnerText = "hoi";
```

The error that I get with that C# code is as follow:

> Value '0' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1.
>       parameters name: index

Comment: GetElementsByTagName would get the element if you had `<searchstring>` tag.

Comment: @L.B, ofcourse, how stupid of me i didn't think about that..

Comment: @L.B, if you make an answer of that, and add this to it, i can mark that as the answer ;)

`HtmlElementCollection playerSearchBox = webBrowserSearchPlayer.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
                playerSearchBox[2].InnerText = "hoi";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be something like this.

```
var input = webBrowserSearchPlayer.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
                    .Cast<HtmlElement>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(i => i.GetAttribute("name") == "searchstring");
```

Comment: Well, thank's for thinking, but is that code better than this: 
`HtmlElementCollection playerSearchBox = webBrowserSearchPlayer.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
                playerSearchBox[2].InnerText = "hoi";`

Comment: @MarcMeesters I think not hardcoding `2` would be better.